# Updated to Xcode 7 Beta 5 and receiving this error: failed with exit code 6

Tags: xcode, xcode7, ios9, xcode7-beta5

I recently updated to Xcode 7 beta 5 and I tried to run my project but it failed with 1 error:

```
Command /Volumes/Xcode 1/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 6
```

I not sure why this is happening as I have never received an error like this. I am new to coding, especially in swift so I would be grateful if you could explain in detail the problem and how to fix it in detail.

Comment: That's a strange place to have Xcode installed.  Please explain.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It was resolved with refreshing account by opening (form the top menu) Xcode-Preferences-Accounts-View Details and clicking on "refresh" (circled arrow) button.

Comment: I also had to remove the derived data. After that the normal build errors showed and I could fix my project.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the Xcode-beta.app from the mounted .dmg volume to your /Applications directory.

Try running it from that location.  Upon launch, it will want to download a few things, so allow it to do so.

If that doesn't work, give the precise details of how you got the error.